# How do I show all results in an "or" query with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to create a simple search function in my app.

In the model

```
def self.search(search)
    where("title LIKE ?", "%#{search}%") | where("description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

In controller

```
if params[:search]
  @advertisements = Advertisement.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
```

I got an error "undefined method `order' for #".
What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update your search method as

```
def self.search(search)
  where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"))
end
```